# Specify AWS Aurora Engine Version only to Major Version Number in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

I have some Terraform code that creates an AWS Aurora RDS cluster:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  provider                = aws.customer
  cluster_identifier      = "my_id"
  engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version          = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.03.2"
  database_name           = var.db_name
  port                    = var.db_port
  master_username         = var.db_master_username
  master_password         = random_password.sqlpassword.result
  backup_retention_period = 5
  preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
  skip_final_snapshot     = true
  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.default.name
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.rds.id]
  deletion_protection     = true
}
```

This code has been working fine for quite a while until just recently when `terraform apply` fails with this error `Error: Failed to modify RDS Cluster (my_id): InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot upgrade aurora-mysql from 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2 to 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.03.2`

To make a long story short, AWS upgraded the minor version number in a maintenance window and refuses to allow Terraform to downgrade the database.  I'm fine with AWS doing this, but I don't want to have to commit new Terraform code every time this happens.

I tried being less specific in the `engine version` by using `engine_version="5.7.mysql_aurora.2"`, but that failed like this:  `InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot find upgrade target from 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2 with requested version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.`

What would be the appropriate Terraform method to allow the RDS Minor Version to float with modifications performed by AWS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `ignore_changes` lifecycle block to the resource.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  provider                = aws.customer
  cluster_identifier      = "my_id"
  engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version          = "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.03.2"
  database_name           = var.db_name
  port                    = var.db_port
  master_username         = var.db_master_username
  master_password         = random_password.sqlpassword.result
  backup_retention_period = 5
  preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
  skip_final_snapshot     = true
  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.default.name
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.rds.id]
  deletion_protection     = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      engine_version,
    ]
  }
}
```

You can read more about this here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html